# Need help to create a new dataframe (from data on countries over year) with all values from the year 2016

Tags: r

My R knowledge is pretty limited, but I have to an analysis for a project which is due in a few days and was hoping I could get some quick help around here!

I created this dataset https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArVyXA5cSMj2h7Mf07SZaVUSK3421Q?e=GQBfeU
but only want to use the data for the year 2016.

I would either like to create a new data frame containing only those rows which include year = 2016 or do my linear regression with the original data frame, but only using the 2016 data - either way will work fine!

Tried googling this, but I wasn't sure what to search for...

Comment: What are you looking for? An effective way to load only `2016` related data or trying to figure out how to filter `2016` data from your dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a new dataframe with year of 2016 we could use `filter` to filter your dataframe `df`:

```
new_dataframe <- filter(df, year==2016)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(readxl)
co2_open_cvs <- read_excel("path_to_file/co2_open_cvs.xlsx")

library(dplyr)
co2_open_cvs_only_2016 <- co2_open_cvs %>% filter(year == 2016)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly!

Just wondering: what does the "%>%" part do?

Comment: *Pipe operator* from `magrittr` (part of `tidyverse`). Pipe an object forward into a function or call expression. So `x %>% f` is equivalent to `f(x)`, for example: instead of `head(df)` you could use `df  %>% head`. really really useful. for more read
   https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: @dy_by Please add your elaboration to the answer.